# Real directory of the git config file if it's a symbolic link

Tags: git

I have the following tree structure on my Linux machine:

```
~/
|─── .cfg/
|    |─── git
|    └─── local/
|         └─── git
└─── .gitconfig -> ~/.cfg/git
```

The idea is to keep the git configuration in a directory with any other Linux configuration files so I can easily share them between machines. However, there are some settings I need on this machine only (such as `gui.editor`) and may differ on other machines. This is why I have the local file.

The `.cfg/git` file looks like

```
[alias]
    c = commit -m

[include]
    path = local/git
```

and the `.cfg/local/git` has some extra configuration

```
[alias]
    asdf = c "asdf"
```

However, this does not seem to work, as I get the following error

```
user@machine:~$ git asdf
git: 'asdf' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
The most similar command is
    add
```

Also

```
user@machine:~$ git config -l --show-origin
file:/home/user/.gitconfig alias.c=commit -m
file:/home/user/.gitconfig include.path=local/git
```

doesn't show the local configuration.

My guess is that the `[include]` is looking in `~` (the directory where the `.gitconfig` link is), instead of `~/.cfg` (where the actual file is). Is there a way to get the actual file location from the configuration file?

What I would like to avoid is

```
[include]
    path = .cfg/local/git
    # or
    path = ~/.cfg/local/git
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Git canonicalizes paths before performing includes, so I don't think this is going to work like you want.  You have a couple of choices:

- Use `~/.gitconfig` for your general config and `~/.config/git/config` for your per-machine config (or vice versa); this is what I do, and it generally works fine.  One or both may be symlinks elsewhere.
- Adopt the approach you dislike.

Note that in the former case, `~/.config` is the default value for `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` as documented in the `git-config(1)` manual page.  You can set that environment variable if you'd like things to look elsewhere.  You can also read more about it at the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html).